# Define a class to write into a file in Python

Tags: python, file, class, oop

In this code I tried to define a class which will write into a file.In the **init** method the name of the file is passed.I also defined a method named "write" to write to the file.Then I created an instance of the class and passed the value of the file name.After that, I called the write method and passed the message to write in the file.At last, I checked if the file is created and if the file has the message.Here's the code:

```
class Logfile(object):
    def __init__(self,file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name

    def write(self,msg):
        with open('self.file_name','w') as myFile:
            myFile.write(msg)

log = Logfile('myNewFile.txt')
log.write("this is a log file.")

with open('myNewFile.txt','r') as readFile:
    read_file = readFile.read()

    for line in read_file:
        print(line)
```

But, it shows an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myNewFile.txt'

This python code is saved in a desktop folder called "My Folder".And when I go there, there is really no such file named "myNewFile.txt".

But, if I run the program with the checking part of the code, I mean,this part:

```
with open('myNewFile.txt','r') as readFile:
    read_file = readFile.read()

    for line in read_file:
        print(line)
```

then, there is no error but still the "myNewFile.txt" is not created.

Can you please help me?

Comment: In your `write` method: `'self.file_name'` -> `self.file_name` One is a string, the other one is your member variable

Comment: Oh I got it. So silly of me.Thanks

Comment: You open this :  with open('self.file_name','w') as myFile.  But 'self.filename_name' is not the name of the file.  It is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the `write` method you should write :

```
with open(self.file_name, ‘w’) as my_file
```

because `self.file_name` is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
log = Logfile('myNewFile.txt')
log.write("this is a log file.")

with open('myNewFile.txt','r') as readFile:
    read_file = readFile.read()

    for line in read_file:
        print(line)
```

You could always try to open the file using `with open(log)` because you have already made the .txt file a variable. I have never tried this and have little experience with this type of code, but it could be worth a shot.